# call html form onsubmit in php

Tags: php, javascript, html

Here is the sample code

```
<form name="login" onSubmit="return doLogin()">
   //here is some form elements
</form>
<script type="text/javascript">
function doLogin(){
    //Here is javascript code
}
<script>
<?php      //How call javascript from PHP ?>
```

How can can I call javascript code from PHP.
Sorry for bad code paste..but only in this site i cant post normaly code !

Comment: You can not call javascript directly from PHP. Can you explain exactly what you are trying to do ?

Comment: And need find solution, without changing javascript place . e.c. without make js file

Comment: I am network administrator i use Mikrotik..and from page i get $username=$_POST['username'];
   $linklogin=$_POST['link-login'];
   $linkorig=$_POST['link-orig']; and so on...  An need find solution how pass variables after html post

Comment: PHP is called on server side (creates code for browser), then javascript is called client-side (in browser).

Comment: @JanissLusis > I mean why do you want to call a JS function from PHP. Can you explain in more details what `doLogin()` does and why you would want to call it from PHP?

Comment: `doLogin()` is already called when the form is submitted.  The POSTed values are passed to the url which `doLogin()` calls.  You don't need to call doLogin with php.

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking to post the data to a PHP page? If so you should look into jQuery's Ajax functionality:
http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

If you're looking to submit the form but not do a page change or anything, you would want your JavaScript function to return false.

I took this straight from jQuery's demo page:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "some.php",
    data: { 
        name: "John", 
        location: "Boston" 
    }
}).done(function( msg ) {
    alert( "Data Saved: " + msg );
});
```

You can also get res.responseText where res is passed into the callback

Comment: In other word i need fist to authenticicated from mysql database and after that only to mikrotik server..! ! Finaly all works except when user  press submit button, first of all authenticicate to mysql , and if sucess, to mikrotik server it cant login. All works but problem is i cant pass variables from mikrotik e.c.  $linklogin=$_POST['link-login'];
   $linkorig=$_POST['link-orig']; after  isset($_POST{'blabla']) procedure ...it only problem...

Comment: Updated to have the responseText accessible

Answer (score 0):

You mean after the form POST is authenticated by a MySQL database with a php script, you THEN need to redirect to the Microtik server, but once again you have to pass some of the POSTED values received by the php script...?

You can use php [curl](http://php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php) to redirect after authenticating in your script.  Or, if the Microtik server login accepts GET variables you can maybe try something like

```
<?php
    Header("Location: http://microtikurl/index.php?username=" . $_POST["username"])
?>
```

Or, you can create another HTML page which calls its `doLogin()` function (which redirects to Microtik server), something like this:

```
<?php 
  //  authenticate POSTED values here against MySQL database
?>
<html>
etc...
<body onload="doLogin('<php echo $_POST["username"]; ?>');">
<script type='text/javascript'>
    function doLogin(username) {
      // etc...
      // use `window.location = ''`, or ajax, or create and `submit()` a hidden form on this page.         }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

> *How can can I call javascript code from PHP. Sorry for bad code paste..but only in this site i cant post normaly code!*

Ask, and you shall receive.

```
<?php
    $jsFunction='window.myJavaScriptFunction';
    echo '<script>'.$jsFunction.'();</script>';
?>
```

Adding arguments is up to you. You just don't get any values returned, unless your JavaScript will post back or something.